# Change button class conditionally based on OData Model

Tags: sapui5

I have a basket, each line containing a button with a tooltip which displays if any internal or Supplier Notes haves been entered.
Here's the view code:

```
<Button text="" icon="sap-icon://notes" tooltip="    {i18n>ReviewBasket.SupplierNote}: {basket>SupplierNote} {i18n>ReviewBasket.InternalNote}: {basket>InternalNote}" press="openSupplierNote"/>​
```

This is great, but I want to change the type of the button to Emphasized if either internal or supplier notes exist.

I've so far logged the model data, which contains all the info.

```
OData: Object
     items: Array[1]
          0: Object
              SupplierNote: "Test1
              InternalNote: "Test2"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the button type with an expression binding.

```
<Button 
    icon="sap-icon://notes" 
    type="{= (${basket>InternalNote} === '' &amp;&amp; ${basket>SupplierNote}) ? 'Accept' : 'Emphasized'}"
    press="openSupplierNote"/>
```

Comment: i'd like to do it this way, but how i only want the button emphasised of basket>InternateNote OR basket>SupplierNote != ''

Comment: Is it possible to write an OR (||) statement for the above ?

Comment: e.g will this work type="{= ${basket>InternalNote} === '' && ${basket>InternalNote} ===''  ? 'Accept' : 'Emphasized'}"

Comment: Sorry I missed the condition, I updated the answer. You need to escape the ampersand as it would break your XML otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help